# Angular2 two way object binding with object returned by method

Tags: json, angular

Angular2 two way data binding is working for json object.
but i want to bind with object which is returned by method call inside the model object.

My `JSON` data as follows,

```
{
"partyId": "1001",
"partyName": "Lifecare Pharmaceuticals",
"partyShortName": null,
"partySecondaryName": null,
"partySecondaryShortName": null,
"sortingName": "Lifecare Pharma",
"mailingName": null,
"address": [{
    "type": "Personal",
    "addressLine1": "",
    "addressLine2": "",
    "addressLine3": "",
    "phone":""
},
{
    "type": "Office",
    "addressLine1": "",
    "addressLine2": "",
    "addressLine3": "",
    "phone":"9876543210"
}]}
```

And blow is my `typescript model class`,

```
 export class Party {
    partyId: string;
    partyName: string;
    partyShortName: string;
    partySecondaryName: string;
    partySecondaryShortName: string;
    sortingName: string;
    mailingName: string;
    address: Array<Address>;

    getOfficeAddress(): Address {
        if(!address) {
            this.address = [];
            this.address.push(new Address());
        }
        let address ;
        this.saleReturnLineItemSet.forEach(addr => {
            if(addr.type == 'Office') {
                address = addr;
            }
        });
        return address;
    }
}

    export class Address {
        type: string;
        addressLine1: string;
        addressLine2: string;
        addressLine3: string;
        phone: string;
    }
```

And this is how am trying to bind it in `input` tag.

```
<input name="phoneNo" [(ngModel)]="party.getOfficeAddress().phone" >
```

Will it possible to bind like this?
or Please suggest a way to do such bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, as a two-way-binding dictates that you can **read** and **write** to the property you are binding to.

You can use a `get` and `set` method for the `phone` instead.

```
get phone(): string {
        if(!this.address) {
            this.address = [];
            this.address.push(new Address());
        }
        let address ;
        this.saleReturnLineItemSet.forEach(addr => {
            if(addr.type == 'Office') {
                address = addr;
            }
        });
        return address.phone;
}

set phone(num: string) { //set the phone number }
```

And in your template, bind to the `phone` directly

```
<input name="phoneNo" [(ngModel)]="phone" >
```

Comment: Hi Fredrik,
 It has some minor bugs in your answer, `if(!address) {` and `<input name="phoneNo" [(ngModel)]="party.phone" >`. 
 It works fine. thanks a lot. it really helpful :-)

Answer (score 1):

This will cause an error `Expression has changed since it was last checked. 
Binding to methods that return a new instance of a value every time they are called won't work.

If you cache the created instance and return this cached instance as long as it's content doesn't actually need to be changed, then it will work fine.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your quick response,
Here am not creating new instance on everytime.
creating at one time and cached in `address` array.

Comment: You need to change `if(!address) {` to `if(!this.address) {` then

Comment: `address = addr;` probably results in a new instance every time, and ` return address;` should then also be ` return this.address;`

Comment: oh yes. sorry it was my typing error. actually i used `if(!this.address)`
 So returing object inside loop resovles my prob ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "So returing object inside loop resovles my prob"

Comment: `getOfficeAddress(): Address {
        return this.address[0];
    }` is also not working.

Comment: its not binding with `input` tag. and the value of '`phone` is not displaying in `input tag

Comment: Sorry, don't know. I can't make sense of your code. I just tried to give a general answer.

Comment: i just created an `Address` and kept in address array.
 now the `address` array should have atleast one Address object.
 am returing Address in 0th position to bind with input tag.
 I know this is logically not satisfy my requirement.
 but somehow trying to show value of `phone` in `input` tag.

Comment: I don't know what could go wrong. This should just work. Try to reproduce in a Plunker.